# Ball is the closure of another ball

Tags: real-analysis

> Give an example where $C(x,\epsilon)$ is the closure of $B(x,\delta)$, and another where $C(x,\epsilon)$ contains the closure of $B(x,\delta)$ as a proper subset.

I'm calling the metric space $X$ with the usual metric. In the first case, can we choose $C(x,\epsilon) := \{y \in X : d(x,y) \leq \delta\}$ and $B(x,\delta) := \{z \in X : d(x,z) < \delta\}$? And in the second example, do we just extend the upper bound of $d(x,y)$ to some arbitrary constant which is greater than $\delta$, say $\delta + 1$, since then $C(x,\epsilon)$ would contain more than just the closure of $B(x,\delta)$?

Comment: Your examples are correct, but you need to show that they are correct.

Comment: Do you want to do this where $\epsilon = \delta$?

Comment: For the first example, do you mean $X = \mathbf{R}$ with the usual metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're meant to do this with $\delta = \epsilon$ or else the problem isn't as interesting.

For the first question, where $C(x,\delta)$ is the closure of $B(x,\delta)$ you know that this is true in the real numbers so there's your example.

For the second question, imagine that there are gaps between your numbers like $X = \mathbf{Z}$. What happens when you look at an open/closed ball with an integer radius compared with a non-integer radius?

Comment: For the second question I just arbitrarily chose $\delta + 1$ as the radius to show that it's bigger that $\delta$... I assume the result would be the same if I chose any positive real number greater than $\delta$?

Comment: @rory_c No, it depends on your metric space. If you take $X = 2\mathbf{Z}$ then you can have $B(x,\delta) = B(x, \delta + 1)$ if $\delta$ is an odd integer. If you take a discrete metric space then $B(x,\delta) = X$ for all $\delta \ge 1$.

Comment: And specifically, with $X = 2\mathbf{Z}$ you get $B(0, 1/2) = C(0, 3/2)$.

Comment: Ah, ok. So once I let X =$\mathbb{R}$ everything I said works?

Comment: @rory_c Yes, but again, it's more interesting if you try to get $\overline{B(x,\delta)} \subsetneq C(x, \delta)$ with the same radius.